# Nested Forms - Ajax Delete

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have a nested form structure as follows:

```
class List < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :restaurants, :dependent => :destroy
end

class Restaurant < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :list
end
```

I can add restaurant items to a particular list in the same form where I create/edit a list. In order to nest the restaurant items within the list form I do the following:

```
 <%= f.fields_for :restaurants do |builder| %>
        <%= render 'restaurant_fields', f: builder %>
 <% end %>
 <%= link_to_add_fields "+ add to stack", f, :restaurants %>
```

The restaurants field partial has a link to remove an item:

```
<%= link_to "remove stack item", '#', class: "remove_fields" %>
```

The jquery (coffeescript) for these actions is as follows:

```
jQuery ->
  $('form').on 'click', '.remove_fields', (event) ->
    $(this).prev('input[type=hidden]').val('1')
    $(this).closest('fieldset').hide()
    event.preventDefault()

  $('form').on 'click', '.add_fields', (event) ->
    time = new Date().getTime()
    regexp = new RegExp($(this).data('id'), 'g')
    $(this).before($(this).data('fields').replace(regexp, time))
    event.preventDefault()
```

When I click on remove stack item, I want to send an ajax request so that the stack item (restaurant) is not only hidden from the view (see above), but also the actual record is deleted at the same time. How would you advise I go about this?

Comment: have a look at this http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2?view=asciicast it will be a good tutorial for these kind of things

Answer (score 0):

You can pass in the `_destroy` param to do so:
Example attributes received from the client:

```
"restaurant" => { "stack_item" => { "id" => "987", "_destroy" => "1" } }
```

You will need to enable the :allow_destroy option on the association in the `Restaurant` model too.

See more here : [Active Record Nested Attributes](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html)

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. This is the same that's done in the Railscasts tutorial. I think what the OP is asking for is a way to destroy the nested object at the time the remove_fields link is pressed. With this answer, you still have to send the whole form in order to perform the deletion.